# No return statement in sub-functions? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm in Chapter 3 - Functions of [*Eloquent Javascript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html).

Everything about the following code makes sense to me -- except one thing.

Why don't the sub-functions (for lack of a better term) have return statements?

```
var landscape = function() {
var result = "";
var flat = function(size) {
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += "_";
  };
  var mountain = function(size) {
    result += "/";
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += "'";
    result += "\\";
  };

  flat(3);
  mountain(4);
  flat(6);
  mountain(1);
  flat(1);
  return result;
};

console.log(landscape());
// → ___/''''\______/'\_
```

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental about the purpose of the return statement, even after reading different definitions from different sources.

I've tried adding return statements to the sub-functions. I've found that it'll either terminate the sub-function pre-maturely, or produce the same result as if it was never there.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The subfunctions don't have individual results either (they just manipulate the `result` variable). What values would you have expected them to return, and how would those be used at the call location?

Comment: A function doesn't need a `return` statement. If the execution reaches the end of the body, it just ends the function (and returns `undefined`).

Comment: @Bergi Well, even after reading a few definitions and looking at a few examples, it wasn't clear to me exactly what it means to '`return` a value'. That's becoming more apparent, now.

I hadn't been exposed to the concept of outer- and function-scoped variables until @suren-srapyan's answer and example.

But even after Suren's post, I still didn't quite understand it until I read your comment ("The subfunctions don't have individual results either (they just manipulate the `result` variable). Then it all came together. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are accessing the outer scoped variable `result` and change something there. So they change the actual `result` variable's value and doesn't need to return anything. If it reaches to the end of the function, function ends. You can do the same by creating local function scoped variables and make strings from them, return them and concatenate in the main `landscape` function.

See the alternative of your code with the return statements

```js
var landscape = function() {

  var result = "";

  var flat = function(size) {
    var localFlat = ''; // Function scoped variable
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++) {
      localFlat += "_";
    }
    return localFlat; // Return function scoped variable
  };
  
  var mountain = function(size) {
    var localMountain = "/"; // Function scoped variable
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++) {
      localMountain += "'";
    }
    localMountain += "\\";
    return localMountain; // Return function scoped variable
  };

  result = flat(3) + mountain(4) + flat(6) + mountain(1) + flat(1); // Concatenate the results of each function

  return result;
};

console.log(landscape());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your sub-functions affect your global landscape variable - result and in the end, function return result variable..This example shows you that you can change global variables into sub-functions..